# get clean bootstrap friendly html output from ckeditor

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, ckeditor, editor, ckeditor.net

i am using ckeditor for one of my blogs , so far i am very happy with the addons and other great stuff ckeditor provides us. but i am stuck at the issue of responsive and seo friendly html output generation[clean html with no inline css and with bootstrap responsive classes].

i want ckeditor html to be cleaned and have pure bootstrap version of html output as much as possible. i know summernote does that , but ckeditor is a more complete tool than summernote so i cant switch to that.

i tried finding on google but so far haven't found any good  example of doing so. i am using latest version of ckeditor avail on website.

a minor implemention and how to would be great for me start in this stuff.

Comment: You need to configure allowable attributes. What is the specific problem?

Comment: @charlietfl i am trying to get clean html output , which contains minimum or no style tags replaced by bootstrapped classes for them. example style="text-align:center" should be class="text-center" and so on

Comment: what difference would it make for that example? have you read the config docs for allowed attributes and style properties?

Comment: yes i have gone through the documentation, it doesnt have what i am looking for. as for why is it important , lets say i get a messy inline css html output that i have to display in my blog page built on bootstrap. now if image tag is combined with bootstrap classes like img-responsive it will look great but when it comes to <img style="width:100px;height:230px;text-align:left""></img> and so it will make the end html ugly in responsive views. no need to mention that inline css is a big no for seo ranking/index in google/search engines.

Comment: also please look at output of summernote if you can it uses the bootstrap classes most of the times. and output is very clean like hand coded html.